# Torrents slow down to a crawl

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, bittorrent, usb-2, qbittorrent

Recently I started noticing qBittorrent slow down to a crawl (from 5MB/s down to 1-3 kilobytes per second)

Bear in mind, this is with a dozen or so extremely well-seeded torrents on top tier private trackers (PTP etc). Sometimes these have thousands of seeds.

It's also evident that the slowdowns are not related to individual torrents because when my speed drops, it affects every torrent. Everything just virtually stops downloading.

It usually fixes it when I restart qBittorrent.

Could this be related to overloading the disk speed or something like that? I'm writing to an extern harddrive via USB 2.0, which I understand is quite limited. But I've been doing that for fifteen years and never had this issue.

I'm not sure if I only noticed because I've been downloading a lot in the past few days or if it happened because I started downloading a lot more in the past few days (with a dozen or so simultaneous downloads).

Comment: If it was me, then I would try and do a speedtest, both when the speed was fast and when it was slow. Well-knowing, that the download influences the result of the speed-test. But just to have some kind of indication, if it was your internet. I would also try with a cables connection (and not WiFi), to ensure that your local setup isn't the faulty part. And lastly - I would try and see if you didn't restart qBittorrent, if the speed 'picked back up' by itself after a while. To ensure that you're not falling for the logic that proofs that rain-dances work. :-D

Comment: Thanks for the reasoned response. I have not done speed tests yet, no. It's not the easiest thing to catch it when it starts going slow, to load up a speed test and try it. However when the speeds do slow down in qB, speeds remain the same in Internet Download Manager (IDM). Closing IDM does not help. I may still try a speedtest soon. But that tells me it's probably not the wifi itself. And to the last question, yes, it does go back up if I leave it for a while, however it is an immediate and reliable effect every time I restart qBittorrent (I have a sample size of about a few dozen restarts).

Comment: As a followup, it does appear based on a somewhat more limited sample size that reducing the max simultaneous DLs resolves the problem and keeps the DL speed maxed out and much more stable. I will update later when I'm more certain about this.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing your findings. I don't have any experience with qB. But let's say that it was leeching off the hosts: A and B. Let's say that they started gaming online at once, then naturally, the speed would slow down. Now the system has to decide: 'When to stick with the host and when to switch to another'. If you close it back down and start it up, then it will most likely test the speed for A and B and see that they're still gaming, so giving you a better host to leech from. So it kinda makes sense that it works as it does. Maybe there is a setting, to change host faster?